# Cast implied unsigned integer type?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and have seen code such as `(unsigned)b`

Does that imply that b will be an unsigned int? Or what type does it imply?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the unsigned datatype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171839/what-is-the-unsigned-datatype)

Comment: `b` could one of many different types.  The result `(unsigned)b` will be `unsigned` AKA `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` will be whatever type it was to begin with. That doesn't change

`(unsigned)b` will *evaluate* as whatever value `b` is, but that is subject to the **cast** to `unsigned`, which is synonymous with `unsigned int`.

How that happens depends entirely on the type of `b` to begin with, whether that type is convertible to `unsigned int`, and whether the *value* contained therein falls unscathed between `0...UINT_MAX` or not.

Ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(unsigned int x)
{
    printf("%u\n", x);
}

int main()
{
    int b = 100;
    foo((unsigned)b); // will print 100

    char c = 'a';
    foo((unsigned)c); // will print 97 (assuming ASCII)

    short s = -10;    // will print 4294967286 for 32-bit int types 
                      // (see below for why)
    foo((unsigned)s);

    // won't compile, not convertible
    //struct X { int val; } x;
    //foo((unsigned)x);
}
```

The only part of this that may raise your eye brow is the third example. When a value of a convertible type to an unsigned type is out of the unsigned type's range (ex: negative values are not same-value representable with *any* `unsigned` target types), the value is converted by repeatedly added the maximum value representable by the unsigned target plus-one to the out-of-range value until such time as it falls within the valid range of the unsigned type.

In other words, because `-10` is not within the valid representation of `unsigned int`, `UINT_MAX+1` is added to `-10` repeatedly (only takes once in this case) until the result is within `0...UINT_MAX`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`unsigned` is a short of `unsigned int`

`signed` is a short of `signed int`

`long` is the short of `long int`

`long long` is the short of `long long int`

`short` is the short of `short int`

Comment: `char` isn't a modifier - there's no such thing as `char int`.

Comment: Oups..I rectified it !! Thanks @sepp2k !

Comment: I think the OP was asking about the meaning of the cast operator.