# What does 'unsigned' mean when it's all by itself?

Tags: c

I came across some C code which has 'unsigned' declaring a variable all by itself, like this:

```
unsigned crc = 0;
```

I think this is very strange because I'd expect an explicit variable type here.  I'm surprised that there aren't any compiler warnings or errors (MDK-Lite 5.12).

So, is this valid, and what kind of variable does it produce?

Comment: Read here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/arithmetic_types

Comment: Certainly a duped, yet I like top rated answer here more.  (Contains a C reference)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [C specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), section 6.7.2:

> — unsigned, or unsigned int

Meaning that `unsigned`, when not specified the type, shall default to  `unsigned int`. So writing `unsigned a` is the same as `unsigned int a`.

Comment: Defined in **6.7.2 Type specifiers**...

Comment: Thanks for the specific pointer. Added a comment referencing that.