# unsigned cast 32 bits

Tags: c, types, casting, integer

On a 32 bits system, what is the behavior of a simple `unsigned` cast ?

For example, let's say I have a `long var = 1`, would `(unsigned)var` cast it to an `unsigned long` or an `unsigned int` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171839/what-is-the-unsigned-datatype : unsigned really is a shorthand for unsigned int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the unsigned datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171839/what-is-the-unsigned-datatype)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accoprding to the C Standard (6.7.2 Type specifiers, p.#2)

> 2. ...Each list of type specifiers shall be one of the following multisets (delimited
>      by commas, when there is more than one multiset
>      per item); the type specifiers may occur in any order, possibly
>      intermixed with the other declaration specifiers.

```
...
— unsigned, or unsigned int
...
— unsigned long, or unsigned long int
```

So the type specifier in the cast expression `( unsigned )` denotes the type `unsigned int`.

If you want to cast to `unsigned long` then you should write either `( unsigned long )` or `( usigned long int )`. And as it is written in the quote you may use any order of type specifiers as for example `( int long unsigned )`.