# what is default type in the following code

Tags: c

I have following code in a CRC16 generator

```
unsigned crc16dnp_byte(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len)
```

what is default type for `void const *mem`? is it `char  pointer`
is `mem` `char pointer`?
thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "default type"? A `void const*` **is** a type...

Comment: The variable `mem` is a pointer to constant data. That's it. `void *` can point to anything, there's no "default" type.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171839/what-is-the-unsigned-datatype) has answers to your question.

Comment: thanks so basically void const *mem is a type and points to constant data that can be an array of ints

Comment: `mem` could be pointing to an array of `int` values, a single `struct` object, an array of `struct` objects, or even a single `double` value. It doesn't matter what it's pointing to. Judging by the name, the function will probably just treat it as a pointer to an array of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

For discussion, we can put `const` aside. It "just" modifies the objects pointed to by `mem` to be read-only, independent of the underlying type. Please note that the pointer `mem` is not constant, but this is just being picky.

Now we have a pointer with the data type `void*`. Please note that there is no concept of a "default" type in C, all expressions have a defined type.

Assuming from the function's name, this pointer is used to calculate a 16 bit cyclic redundancy check value. Such calculations are done on the binary representation of the objects to check, independent of their data type. The theory behind CRC uses a bit as the type of the data. However, commonly the calculation is done with bytes, in C represented by `char`.

The C standard says this to pointers (excerpts):

> A pointer to **`void`** may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type.

> When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object.

Therefore, to make life easy, the author chose `void*`. You can provide a pointer to any object without the need to cast it or to think of alignment.